# Maximum length is 128. Incorrect syntax near '+'

Tags: sql-server, rpa, uipath

I'm using following query for the RPA-UiPath and trying to read it through Excel config file. I'm getting the error:

> Maximum length is 128.
> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

What changes I need make in order to use the query?

Whenever I'm passing the same query directly or through the variable, I'm not facing any issue.

> Error :  Execute Non Query: The identifier that starts with 'INSERT
> INTO table_name (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D, COLUMN_E,
> COLUMN_F, COLUMN_G) VAL' is too long. Maximum length is 128. Incorrect
> syntax near '+'.

```
"INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D, COLUMN_E, COLUMN_F, COLUMN_G)
VALUES ('"+Convert.ToDecimal(in_TransactionItem("Id").ToString.Trim).ToString+"','"+in_TransactionItem("Number").ToString.Trim+"','"+in_TransactionItem("VIN").ToString.Trim+"','"+CHSDUEDATE.ToString+"','"+in_TransactionItem("Style").ToString.Trim+"','"+in_TransactionItem("Line").ToString.Trim+"','"+in_TransactionItem("Year").ToString.Trim.Substring(in_TransactionItem("Model_Year").ToString.Length-2)+"')"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks to me that one of your values item strings (e.g. `in_TransactionItem("Line")`) is larger than defined in your database. So, how does this whole string look like when you show (e.g. in the debug pane)? (Add that to the question)

Comment: Added, could you be kind enough to help me out?

Comment: If you Convert.ToDecimal (so it's a numerical value), why do you wrap the result in quotes (which is a varchar value)?

Comment: [Use parameters](https://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet) to supply the values. The max length issue may go away and you get protected against sql-injection (what *is* the final command you are trying to execute?).

Comment: Do you mean you read this entire string (as posted) from a config file? Then it will not understand that "in_TransactionItem" is some variable

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, yes, It's not reading it from Excel config file, but if we directly use the same query from UiPath, then not facing any issue.

Comment: Please, post the query that is executed after all the variables expanded. Obviously, SQL Server does not understand your statement and tries to use all the statement as identifier, not as `insert`

Comment: When you have this expression as part of your code, the variables (like `in_TransactionItem("Id")`) are expanded to their values before the command is sent to the database. When you get the same expression-string from a configuration file, none of this happens and the database gets a string it doesn't understand. You will need to rethink this part of your code, preferably with parameter placeholders